# How do i read csv file by rows selectively using php

Tags: php, csv

For example i have a csv file with 5 rows. While reading csv file using fgetcsv function, how do i skip first 2 rows and directly start reading from 3rd row ?

Comment: Put a count in with your read file line loop, and an if test that ignores rows if count < 2.... there is no magic way of doing it

Comment: Of course, if you're doing LOAD DATA INFILE to transfer CSV data to a MySQL database, you can specify this is the SQL statement

Comment: By this way i will need to use fgetcsv 5 times...but require to use 3 times.

Comment: Yes you will, that's how you need to do it